# efficiently use the memory of GPU in matlab

Tags: matlab, memory-management, gpu

I am using GPU for computation in matlab. And I keep on getting `Out of memory` problem.
So I think I could convert some of my variables from `double`, which is the default type of matlab, to `single`. Then I did the following experiment

```
A = gpuArray([1,2,3])
A = 
1  2  3

whos A
Name   Size   Bytes  Class
A      1*3     4     gpuArray

B = gpuArray(single([1,2,3]))
B = 
1*3 gpuArray single row vector
1  2  3

whos B
Name   Size   Bytes  Class
B      1*3     4     gpuArray
```

Now I am a little bit confusing. On one hand, it does show me that `B` is a `1*3 gpuArray single row vector`. However, on the other hand, the `whos` command shows no difference between `A` and `B`.

I am wondering if this `double` to `single` conversion will indeed help me reduce the memory usage of my GPU in matlab. Basically, my question is: when I move 2 variables on cpu, one is `double` and the other is `single`, to gpu, do they consume same amount of memory of GPU in matlab? `whos` command shows no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the following:

```
A = gpuArray([1:1000])
whos A
  Name      Size              Bytes  Class       Attributes

  A         1x1000                4  gpuArray
```

Interesting! Only 4 bytes!
But this has an easy explanation: `whos` is only giving you the size of the variable on CPU RAM. Its 4 bytes because its just a memory address, not the data itself. The data is on the GPU, and it can not "easily" be accessed by the CPU.

Answering your question: Yes, `single` will take half of the memory of `double` on the GPU.

Comment: Yes, I also did an experiment myself. I have 2 codes which are exactly the same, except that one code I define all variables as single. Then the other code gives me out of memory error, while the all single code is able to run successfully.